# Side effects on my code

Tags: java, effects

I dont currently know a lot about side effects within programming, so I was curious as to wether my code below has any side effects.

```
class Factorial {  

   static int factorial(int n) {    
      if (n == 0)    
         return 1;    
      else    
         return(n * factorial(n-1));    
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {  
      int number = 4; // It is the number to calculate factorial    
      int fact = factorial(number);   
      System.out.println("Factorial of " + number + " is: " + fact);    
   }  

}
```

Comment: Factorial is pure function, without any side effects.

Comment: What do you mean by side effects exactly?

Comment: Do you mean whether your factorial function will happily return some negative number instead of throwing an exception if its input is too large?  Yes, that side effect exists.

Comment: `main` has the side effect of creating output on `System.out`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`factorial` does not have any side effects because it computes a value and returns it, without modifying anything external to the function. `main`, on the other hand, has the side effect of printing the factorial. This is good design because the `factorial` function should not have any side effects; it should just compute the factorial.

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect